# Yup doesn't work properly with i18n

Tags: reactjs, react-native, localization, internationalization, yup

I have this piece of a code. I want to add error messages depending on user's locale, but yup throws errors, same if fields are filled in incorrectly

[missing "en.login.emailRequiredError" translation]
[missing "en.login.passRequiredError" translation]

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
      .string()
      .email(i18n.t('login.emailSpellError'))
      .required(i18n.t('login.emailRequiredError')),
  password: yup
      .string()
      .matches(/^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,15})$/i, i18n.t('login.passSpellError'))
      .required(i18n.t('login.passRequiredError')),
});
```

i18n.t('login.passRequiredError') works fine when I put it into a render method for checking it but it does not work with the yup. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the variable `i18n` in your example?

Comment: perhaps you could pass `i18n` as a prop to schema? Have you tried turning it into function that accepts i18n as an argument and returns yup object?

Answer (score 19):

In your schema, replace:

```
.email(i18n.t('login.emailSpellError'))
```

with

```
.email('login.emailSpellError')
```

then in your render method:

```
{t(`form.errors.${form.errors.email}`)}
```

This assumes your translation file has an entry like this:

```
"form": { "errors": {"login": {"emailSpellError": "Your email is invalid"}}}}
```

The goal here is to move the t() method into your render method and have all translations happen there.

Comment: The problem with this approach is you can't use variables that are schema specific. For example: a validation of min characters in two different places with each one requiring a different min character count. eg. Min characters: 3 and Min characters 5 on two different form fields cant use the same translation.

Comment: It does not work for me too

Comment: It does work for me on my case with `i18n-js` 

Answer (score 7):

**Yup Validation method**,

```
// You define the key mentioned in the translation file, in my example 'Invalid email' and 'Required'  

    let ForgotPasswordSchema = yup.object().shape({
      email: yup.string().email('Invalid email').required('Required'),
    });
```

**In render method,**

```
// As per your definition

isInvalid={(!!errors.email) && this.context.t(!!errors.email)}
invalidText={(errors.email) && this.context.t(errors.email)}
```

**Translation File**

```
export const translations = {
  "cy": {
    "Required":"Gofynnol",
    "Invalid email":"Nid yw'r cyfeiriad ebost yn ddilys",
}
 };
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution will be to make a function that returns your validation schema. Then call that function in your component with the result memoized.
This way, you are guaranteed that translations for validation messages are computed on the fly.

Another advantage here is you translate at the source of the message.

```
// Translation file
{
  "validation.invalid-email": "Email is invalid",
  "validation.field-required": "Field is required"
}


// Validation schema
const forgotPasswordSchema = () => {
  return yup.object().shape({
    email: yup
      .string()
      .email(i18n.t('validation.invalid-email'))
      .required(i18n.t('validation.field-required')),
  });
};


// Your component
const FormComponent = () => {
  const schema = useMemo(() => forgotPasswordSchema(), [i18n.language]); // NB: `[i18n.language]` is optional and `[]` will suffice depending on how you're handling language change

  return <>...</>;
}
```

Comment: It does not work just after changing the language.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a few custom hooks for this approach

This one to refresh error messages inside schema when is changing app language

```
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useMemo } from 'react';

const useSchema = (getSchema) => {
  const { locale } = useRouter();
  const resolver = useMemo(getSchema, [locale]);

  return yupResolver(resolver);
};

export default useSchema;
```

And this one to set global in App component localised error messages

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { setLocale } from 'yup';

export const useLocalisedYupSchema = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('common');

  setLocale({
    mixed: {
      required: t('validation.required')
    },
    string: {
      min: ({ min }) => t('validation.min', { min }),
      max: ({ max }) => t('validation.max', { max })
    },
  });
};
```

Also usage of schemas inside component with React Hook Form

```
import { getChangePasswordSchema } from 'static/schemas/changePassword';
import useSchema from 'utils/hooks/useSchema';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const AccountContentSecurity = () => {
  ...
  const resolver = useSchema(getChangePasswordSchema);
  const { reset, control, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      'current_password': '',
      'new_password': '',
      'password_confirmation': '',
    },  
    resolver,
  });
  ...
```

and schema

```
import { passwordSchema } from 'static/schemas';
import { object } from 'yup';

export const getChangePasswordSchema = () => object({
  'current_password': passwordSchema,
  'new_password': passwordSchema,
  'password_confirmation': passwordSchema,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when using react-hook-form, I managed to solve the problem by adding useEffect to the form processing hook

```js
export type LoginFormType = {
  captcha: string
  email: string
  password: string
}

export const getLoginFormSchema = (): ObjectSchema<LoginFormType> =>
  yup.object({
    captcha: yup.string().required(i18n.t('Enter code from image')).trim(),
    email: yup
      .string()
      .required(i18n.t('Enter your email'))
      .matches(emailRegex, i18n.t('Enter a valid email address'))
      .trim(),
    password: yup.string().required(i18n.t('Enter the password')).trim(),
  })

export const defaultValues: LoginFormType = {
  captcha: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
}

export const useLoginForm = (defValue?: Partial<LoginFormType>): UseFormReturn<LoginFormType> => {
  const schema = useMemo(() => getLoginFormSchema(), [i18n.language])

  const form = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      ...defaultValues,
      ...defValue,
    },
    mode: 'onSubmit',
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (form.formState.isSubmitted) {
      form.trigger()
    }
  }, [i18n.language])

  return form
}
```